# Есть ли здесь ошибка?

Tags: грамматика

Что в бумаги на писано?

1. Есть ли в предложение ошибка?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Какую фразу надо разобрать? Ошибок-то хватает в обеих, но они совсем уж детские.

Answer (score 2):

I. [бума́га](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0)
2. *перен., разг.* то же, что документ.
Написано (в чём? П. п.) в бумаг**е**.

II. [напи́сано](http://russkiy-na-5.ru/dictionary/morphemics/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE) — краткое страдательное причастие (полное причастие — написанный), ед. ч., ср. род. Пишется слитно, т. к. **на-** — это приставка.

III. [предложе́ние](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)
Есть (в чём? П. п.) в предложени**и**.

Правильно: **Что в бумаге написано?**

*— Кстати, **в твоей бумаге написано**, что тебя зовут Ганс! — возвращая бумаги Алексею, девушка рассмеялась* (М. Карс. Закат рябиновой любви).

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: **Что в бумаге написано?**

Примечание. Это разговорный стиль. А нейтральный стиль будет выглядеть, например, так: **Что в документе написано?**